# How can I use a relative path in my toml file?

Tags: iphone, directory, relative-path, absolute-path, toml

I want to use a relative directory in toml file.
I heard that I should use "\" instead of "" in toml file,
but I don't know how to use relative path in toml file.

```
HatMode = "Custom"
HorizontalSize = 1.5
HatPosition = 0.600000023841858
CustomHatPath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\kane_goose\\DesktopGoose_v0.3_Extractor\\Assets\\Mods\\HatGoos\\kane.png"
```

This is codes inside of toml file.
I should enter a relative path in
`CustomHatPath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\kane_goose\\DesktopGoose_v0.3_Extractor\\Assets\\Mods\\HatGoos\\kane.png"`
this part.

Below, directory of the first image is `C:\Users\username\Desktop\kane_goose\DesktopGoose_v0.3_Extractor\Assets\Mods\HatGoos`
, and directory of the second image is `C:\Users\username\Desktop\kane_goose\DesktopGoose_v0.3_Extractor\Assets\Mods\HatGoos\hat`

The toml file is on the first image, and I must add the `kane.png` of the second image to the toml file.

Can you teach me how to use relative path in this situation? in toml file?

[image]

[image]